# eclipseのVM引数からクラスパスを設定する方法

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, tomcat

eclipseについて質問があります。
外部フォルダにあるpropertiesファイルを
読み込みたいのですが、
eclipseのVM引数から
Javaのビルドパス>ライブラリー>クラスパスの
外部フォルダーを設定する方法はありますか。

よろしくお願いいたします。

補足
Thymeleafを使ってhtmlに直接messages.propertiesの値をを読み込んでいるため、
外部ディレクトリをクラスパスに追加したいです。

Comment: "eclipseのVM引数"というのは`eclipse.ini`(STSなら`SpringToolSuite4.ini`)の`-vmargs`のことで合っていますか？おそらく不可能ですが、実際にやりたいことは何でしょうか。実際にやりたいことによっては代替策があるかもしれません。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。"VM引数"は実行構成のSpring Bootアプリケーションの引数です。実際にやりたいことはmessages.propertiesを外部ディレクトリから読み込み、メッセージ式でhtmlに直接読み込むことをやりたいです。

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse(STS)から実行する際は "Javaのビルドパス>ライブラリー>クラスパスの外部フォルダー" によって外部の `messages.properties` を読めるようにしているが、 `java -jar <spring-bootアプリ>` コマンドで実行する場合にどう指定すれば良いか、という意図の質問ということでよいでしょうか。

---

メッセージソース(リソースバンドル)のロケーション指定は [`spring.massages.basename`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.6.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-internationalization)で行いますが、ここでは`file:`でファイルシステム上のファイル(のベースネーム)を指定することもできます(参考: [How to externalize i18n properties files in spring-boot applications - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39487085/4506703))。

またプロパティ設定はコマンドライン引数で指定できます([4.2.2. Accessing Command Line Properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.6.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-command-line-args))。

したがって、例えば `./external-resources/messages.properties` が読ませたいファイルだとすると、

```sh
java -jar <spring-bootアプリ>.jar --spring.messages.basename=file:external-resources/messages
```

で実現可能です。

[実行サンプルコード](https://github.com/yukihane/stackoverflow-qa/tree/master/so65859/jar-version), [Thymeleafを使ったwarバージョン](https://github.com/yukihane/stackoverflow-qa/tree/master/so65859/war-version)

---

Tomcatにデプロイする場合、Tomcat側に指示する必要があります。設定方法はこちらに詳しいです:

- [Can I create a custom classpath on a per application basis in Tomcat - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26126563/4506703)
- [Apache Tomcat 9 Configuration Reference (9.0.34) - The Resources Component](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/resources.html)

[前出したwar](https://github.com/yukihane/stackoverflow-qa/tree/master/so65859/war-version)をTomcat9にデプロイし `/tmp/external-resources` ディレクトリ配下のメッセージリソースを読む場合を例にすると、

- `messages.properties` ファイルを `/tmp/external-resources/` ディレクトリ下に移動する
- Tomcatの本体配下に `conf/Catalina/localhost/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.xml` ファイルを作成する。内容は次の通り:

```
<Context>
  <Resources>
    <PostResources
      className="org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet"
      base="/tmp/external-resources"
      webAppMount="/WEB-INF/classes" />
  </Resources>
</Context>
```

この設定で `/tmp/external-resources` ディレクトリがwarファイル内 `/WEB-INF/classes` に差し込まれますのでアプリケーションはメッセージリソースをクラスパス内で見つけることができるようになります。

Comment: spring boot applicationで`-Dspring.messages.basename=file:外部ディレクトリ/messages`を指定してみたのですが、読み込まれませんでした。warで実行するため、起動パラメータでクラスパスを追加し、`spring.messages.basename=classpath:`で読み込ませたいです。

Comment: 本文末尾にも追加していますが、[war & thymeleaf](https://github.com/yukihane/stackoverflow-qa/tree/master/so65859/war-version)でも同様の設定で読めています。 "warで実行するため" というのはTomcatなどにデプロイして実行する、という意味でしょうか。"起動パラメータ"とは何を起動するコマンドのパラメータでしょうか。想定している環境や問題が再現するコードなど、もう少し情報が必要かと考えます。

Comment: tomcatにデプロイして実行するという意味合いです。
war-versionで作成していただいたコードで想定している内容はあっています。
環境ですが、お伝えするのが遅れてしまって申し訳ありませんが、こちらのビルドをgradleを用いて行っております。

Comment: 投稿が遅くなりました。デプロイ後にxmlで設定することでファイルが読み込む方法わかりました。ありがとうございます。